# React Native: Only Animate One of Several Elements

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native

I created a React Native component that consists of 5 icons in a row.
The icons are clickable and I want to animate the one that is clicked.

My problem is: When I click an icon, ALL the icons are animated. This is because they are produced in a loop and all given the same properties.

How can I set up my component so that I can somehow only animate the one icon that is pressed?

Here's the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Animated, View, Text, TouchableHighlight, } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
const AnimatedIcon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Icon);

export class IconRow extends React.Component {  

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { iconFontSize: new Animated.Value(50) };
  }

  onIconPress = (index) => {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(this.state.iconFontSize, { toValue: 40, duration: 100 }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.iconFontSize, { toValue: 58, duration: 100 }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.iconFontSize, { toValue: 50, duration: 100 }),
    ]).start();
  }

  renderIcons() {
    var icons = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      icons.push(
        <TouchableHighlight key={i} underlayColor="transparent" onPress={this.onIconPress.bind(this, i)}>       
          <AnimatedIcon name="heart" style={{fontSize:this.state.iconFontSize, color: "red"}} />
        </TouchableHighlight>   
      );        
    }
    return icons;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
          {this.renderIcons()}
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Snack: https://snack.expo.io/HJJ0Edhlz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Eric - I'm unable to test this locally, but I'm pretty sure it will do what you want. If it doesn't work out, please let me know and I'll remove my answer.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Animated, View, Text, TouchableHighlight, } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
const AnimatedIcon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Icon);

export class IconRow extends React.Component {  

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      iconFontSizes: [
        new Animated.Value(50),
        new Animated.Value(50),
        new Animated.Value(50),
        new Animated.Value(50),
        new Animated.Value(50)
      ], 
    };
  }

  onIconPress = (i) => {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(this.state.iconFontSizes[i], { toValue: 40, duration: 100 }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.iconFontSizes[i], { toValue: 58, duration: 100 }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.iconFontSizes[i], { toValue: 50, duration: 100 }),
    ]).start();
  }

  renderIcons() {
    var icons = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.iconFontSizes.length; i++) {
      icons.push(
        <TouchableHighlight key={i} underlayColor="transparent" onPress={this.onIconPress.bind(this, i)}>       
          <AnimatedIcon name="heart" style={{fontSize:this.state.iconFontSizes[i], color: "red"}} />
        </TouchableHighlight>   
      );        
    }

    return icons;
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
          {this.renderIcons()}
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This should work but instead of mutating state, you would need to store them in an array then use `setState` to update the state after the loop.

Comment: @Matt Aft Are the changes I made above what you were proposing?

Comment: yeah, you just didn't need to concat. I just edited that part, but everything else looks good

Comment: @trevor I will test in a moment, but I don't believe you can set the state inside a render method, can you? I get the idea, though.

Comment: @Eric I'm not 100% sure that you can. Like I said, I was unable to test this locally.

Comment: Perfect! I made a small edit regarding the setting state, but this is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, awesome! Do you want to share the edit you made so we can update the answer?

Comment: I edited your actual post, but it says it needs to be peer reviewed. :/ Does it let you approve it? All I did was initialize iconFontSizes[] in the constructor.

Comment: It looks like you need at least 2K reputation to access the suggested edits review queue, so I won't be able to approve it, but someone will. Glad this worked out. Good luck with your project. And thanks to @Matt Aft for collaborating on this.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are creating the whole row of icons that's why you face this problem.

Here you have to create one icon at a time rather than creating a row. 
Like, take a one view for creating a icon and set in one row

```
<View style = {{flexDirection:'row'}} >
    <IconRow />
    <IconRow />
    <IconRow />
    <IconRow />
    <IconRow />
</View>
```

After that, renderIcons function in IconRow class, remove for loop and depended variable 'i' like,

```
icons.push(
        <TouchableHighlight key={1} underlayColor="transparent" onPress={this.onIconPress.bind(this, 1)}>       
          <AnimatedIcon name="heart" style={{fontSize:this.state.iconFontSize, color: "red"}} />
        </TouchableHighlight> 
);
```

or you can iterate for loop only one time like,

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      icons.push(
        <TouchableHighlight key={1} underlayColor="transparent" onPress={this.onIconPress.bind(this, 1)}>       
          <AnimatedIcon name="heart" style={{fontSize:this.state.iconFontSize, color: "red"}} />
        </TouchableHighlight> 
      );
}
```

So it creates only one icon at a time and in a row. If you want to give different key than please change '1' to another value.

Now animate the one that is clicked.

Hope It will be helpful.

Comment: So basically you mean to make a separate component for the icon with the animation? Yes, I believe this would work, however I prefer the answer above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling the same function which has the same reference in each call. Create a new component and loop in that component so each icon will have its own function with a different reference.

this will be the component of Icon

```
const Icon = ({ i }) => {
    const iconFontSize = new Animated.Value(50)

    const onIconPress = () => {
        Animated.sequence([
          Animated.timing(iconFontSize, { toValue: 40, duration: 100 }),
          Animated.timing(iconFontSize, { toValue: 58, duration: 100 }),
          Animated.timing(iconFontSize, { toValue: 50, duration: 100 }),
     ]).start();}



    return (
        <TouchableHighlight key={i} underlayColor="transparent" onPress {onIconPress}>       
          <AnimatedIcon name="heart" style={{fontSize: iconFontSize, color: "red"}} />
        </TouchableHighlight>   
    )
}
```

Bellow will be the parent component where you will import the above Icon component and loop on that. Now in each loop you will have a component and animated functions associated only with that component.

```
const IconRow = ({ }) => {
    renderIcons = () => {
      var icons = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        icons.push(<Icon i={ i } />);        
      }
      return icons;
    }

    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
          {renderIcons()}
        </View> 
    )
}
```